# 0x2746 Error msodbcsql connection to SQL Server 2016

Tags: 20.04, mssql, odbc

I am getting a error when trying to use `sqlcmd` against my SQL Server 2016 database.

I can successfully get a connection to  on port 1433

```
(venv) xxxx@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/etc$ telnet xx.xxx.xxx.202 1433
Trying xx.xxx.xxx.202...
Connected to xx.xxx.xxx.202.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The server is answering however, when I try the following:

```
(venv) xxxx@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/etc$ sqlcmd -S xx.xxx.xxx.202 -U sa -P password
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.
```

I am successful using other OBDC drivers such as FreeTDS using isql, but FreeTDS driver with sqlcmd yeilds 'Unsupported driver message'.

Anyone have similiar issues or thoughts about how to resolve?

#### Update

Client Info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

ODBCinst.ini:

```
[SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1
UsageCount=1

[FreeTDS]
Description=v0.91 with protocol v7.2
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

SQL Server Version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU8) (KB4077064) - 13.0.4474.0 (X64)
Feb 24 2018 13:53:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) 
on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research, trial and error.  I found resolution in my problem with upgrading openssl (1.1.1f) to a later version I used (1.1.1k).

Following the instructions on this post:
[How to fix Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289910/1341257)

Even though this was for a different error.  Upgrading openssl fixed my TCP Provider 0x2746 error.